# Copy and paste based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am attempting to loop through various workbooks and paste data into another "merge" workbook based on cell values.

Workbook A sheet contains the data I want to loop through and copy along with the adjacent two columns.

Workbook B is where I want to paste the data.

Workbook A - Column A contains numeric values. I want to copy the cells  A2, B2, C2 of data only if column A2's value is between 1-299. Paste these copied cells in two workbook B- columns A, B, C starting below where the last values where pasted.

Then loop through the next row checking if its value is between 1-299.

I will then apply this to many spreadsheets, but for now I just want to get one copy and paste working so I can understand how to apply it.

Comment: Can you post something you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

How much knowledge of VBA do you have? You could try to change the following code that I've been using for something similar, although it has an input box.

```
    Option Compare Text
Public Sub TeamReport()
    Dim strFind As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim wsFind As Worksheet
    Dim wsPaste As Worksheet

    strFind = InputBox("Enter Team Name Here")

    Set wsFind = Sheets("Complete Listing")

    Set wsPaste = Sheets("Team Report")


    j = 3


Worksheets("Team Report").Range("A3:DJ300").ClearContents
    For i = 2 To wsFind.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If wsFind.Range("C" & i) = strFind Then
            wsFind.Range(i & ":" & i).Copy Destination:=wsPaste.Range(j & ":" & j)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i


Worksheets("Team Report").Select
End Sub
```

It has a input box to find a specific value, but might be able to get you started.